# Quelle est la fonction de « à sa suite » ici ?

Tags: sens, locutions, paroles-de-chanson

Pourriez-vous m’aider à comprendre ce morceau d’une chanson ?

> Un grand aigle qui planait dans le ciel,
>   s'est posé pour me faire monter sur son aile,
>   **À sa suite**, dans le vent je me suis vu,
>   au cortège des espèces disparues.

Je ne sais pas ce que « à sa suite » veut dire ici. J’ai cherché un éclaircissement sur la toile mais je n’ai rien trouvé de satisfaisant. Bien entendu, je connais le mot *suite*, Je connais des tournures dont ce mot fait partie. Néanmoins, aucune de ces tournures ne convient vraiment avec le récit.

Je sais que « à sa suite » a quelque chose avoir avec l’aile de l’aigle, puisque le nom commun *aile* est le seul dont le genre convient à « sa ». Voici toutes les combinaisons de mots apparentées auxquelles j’ai pensé.

- *En suivant l’aile* Cela ne convient pas car le personnage est assis *sur* ses ailes.
- *Grâce à l’aile.* J’y pense car je me rappelle la locution *à la suite de*. Elle me laisse penser que l’enchaînement de mots entre guillemets veut dire *à la suite de ce que l’oiseau fait*. Cette façon de dire a toutefois quelque chose de recherché.
- *Ensuite* m’est aussi venu à l’esprit, quoiqu’il n’y ait pas de rapport avec l’aile de l’oiseau ici.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selon moi dans cette phrase « à sa suite » signifie « à la suite de l'aigle », c'est-à-dire « en suivant l'aigle ».

Le personnage ne suit en effet pas l'aigle mais il s'imagine le faire. Il dit « je me suis vu à sa suite dans le cortège ». Ici *je me suis vu* signifie *je me suis imaginé en train de*. Il s'imagine le suivre dans le « cortège des espèces disparues », ce qui veut dire de manière imagée que le personnage fait partie avec l'aigle d'un même groupe, le groupe des *espèces disparues*. Ce qui peut se comprendre de différentes manières : peut-être l'auteur de la chanson s'imagine-t-il être une espèce disparue, il s'imagine être le dernier des poètes ...

Un cortège c'est un groupe de personnes qui se réunit pour marcher dans un même but, comme dans une manifestation par exemple. Faire partie d'un même cortège, cela signifie partager les mêmes idéaux.

Une petite remarque : le genre de « sa » dans « à sa suite » ne vient pas du "propriétaire" de la « suite », mais du mot « suite » directement, qui est féminin. Par exemple :

- A la suite de mon frère → à sa suite
- A la suite de ma soeur → à sa suite
- Au retour de mon frère → à son retour
- Au retour de ma soeur → à son retour

C'est toujours pareils avec les pronoms possessifs en français, le genre vient du nom auquel il se rapporte, pas du propriétaire (en anglais c'est l'inverse) :

- Le vélo de ma soeur → son vélo
- Le vélo de mon frère → son vélo
- La maison de ma soeur → sa maison
- La maison de mon frère → sa maison

Comment: Merci pour m’avoir averti que je me suis planté de la grammaire.

Answer (score 1):

*Suite* a de nombreuses significations.

Ici *à sa suite* signifie que l'on est dans le cortège qui accompagne l'aigle, que l'on fait partie de ceux qui suivent un personnage dont on dépend.

> Le roi s'est déplacé à Blois, *à sa suite* courtisans et favoris se querellent pour être parmi les premiers.

Comme l'auteur est monté sur l'aile de l'aigle, "il voyage dans le carrosse du roi", il est l'invité d'honneur et a obtenu une place privilégiée, place qui lui donne un point de vue 'royal' (ou plutôt aquilin) sur le monde des rêves et de l'imagination.

N.B. : Le vent et le dernier souffle des disparus sont de même nature, l'extrait est trop bref pour en dire plus.